# Create a new sheet for every value in column A and import a template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that I use different queries to pull information.  I am wanting to branch these into their own sheet.

I want to make a new sheet for every name in column A and rename it accordingly.  I want the new sheet to have that name be placed in cell A1.
I also have a formula I want to be placed in A2.  (The formula could be built in script of pulled from a random cell~doesn't matter)

Built in google but can also switch to Excel if needed
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DC8wjW79AU8XvyHrcmcsMxpEK1m4lVIEe4trMnM1CWo/copy)

This is what I have been trying to build from but no success. My original script takes the list and makes new tabs, the second function places the name in cell A1...instead of tabs want a sheet and need functions to work together

```
function dupsheetsTemp()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      temp = ss.getSheetByName('Master'),
      all = ss.getSheetByName('Students'),
      sheets = ss.getSheets(),
      vals = all.getRange('a:b').getValues();

  for (var i = 0, len = sheets.length, names = []; i < len; i++)
    names.push(sheets[i].getName());

  for (var i = vals.length-1; i > 0; i--)
  {
    var name = vals[i][0];
    if (name !='' && names.indexOf(name) == -1)
    {
      temp.activate();
      ss.duplicateActiveSheet()
        .setName(vals[i][0])
        .getRange(1, 1).setValue(vals[i][1]);
    }
  }
}

function sheetNames() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .getSheets()
        .forEach(function (s) {
            s.getRange('A1')
                .setValue(s.getName())
        });
}
```

Comment: Had a macro through excel that created a new sheet and named it but locked up at the first name.  I haven't started to build a script yet (not my strength).

Comment: This is what I have been trying to build from but no success.  My original script takes the list and makes new tabs, the second function places the name in cell A1.

Comment: To create a new `Spreadsheet` object, rather than just a new `Sheet` object (aka "tab", "worksheet"), you need to call `SpreadsheetApp.create`. If you want to control where that file is made, you need to use `DriveApp` methods to move it, or directly create a file of a designated [`mimeType`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type) with `Folder#createFile` from your active workbook's `Folder`. Note you may find copying a worksheet and using that as a template for `insertSheet` useful.

Comment: @SHAWNWINDERS Hi. I'm looking at older questions that don't seem to have been resolved. How did you get on? Did you resolve your problem, or are you still looking for help?